# RHEL 5.3 - proxy_pass does not resolve DNS using /etc/hosts

Tags: rhel, reverse-proxy

I have enabled reverse proxy on Apache Web server.
Included below parameters in alm.conf file

```
ProxyPass /almbin http://172.1x.xxx.xx:80/almbin/
ProxyPassReverse /almbin http://172.1x.xxx.xx:80/almbin/
```

in httpd.conf:

```
Include conf.d/alm.conf
```

Made entry in /etc/hosts file as below:

```
alm.test.com     172.1x.xxx.xx:80   almTest
```

But I am not able to redirect in on Internet. IP address i.e. 172.1x.xxx.xx:80/almbin/ works but when tried with host name alm.test.com it gives error as DNS cannot be resolved.

Comment: Perhaps you're not using /etc/hosts.  What does /etc/nsswitch.conf contain on the "hosts:" line?  "files" should be first.  And the syntax of your /etc/hosts is wrong.  Should be `172.1x.xxx.xx  almTest alm.test.com`.  IP address first, and no port number!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you don't own `test.com` (so stop using it, use `.local` or something).  Nobody on the internet is ever going to try resolving test.com addresses by querying your server.
2. you're not even running a DNS server, so even if you had that domain and it was delegated to your server, there's nothing running to answer queries about it.  An `/etc/hosts` file is seen only by the host it is installed on.
3. `172.1x.x.x` - i'll guess that's in the range 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255.  That's an [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) private IP address, not routed on the internet - used for internal networks only.